# Cant connect to django process running in container with vs-code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Im having trouble connecting to a django process running inside a container spawned with vs-code. Everything seem to be working and I get the startup message for the server, but when connecting to localhost:8000, I get no response...

I get a published port message when starting the container:

> Published Ports: 8000/tcp -> 127.0.0.1:8000

and also a clean start when starting launch.json debug

> System check identified no issues (0 silenced). October 13, 2019 -
>   17:45:05 Django version 2.2.6, using settings 'fpl-django.settings'
>   Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server
>   with CONTROL-C.

Why cant I access the site on: localhost:8000?

devcontainer.json:

```
    // For format details, see https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/devcontainer.json or the definition README at
// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/master/containers/docker-existing-dockerfile
{
  "name": "Existing Dockerfile",
  // Sets the run context to one level up instead of the .devcontainer folder.
  "context": "..",
  // Update the 'dockerFile' property if you aren't using the standard 'Dockerfile' filename.
  "dockerFile": "../docker/dev/python/Dockerfile",
  // The optional 'runArgs' property can be used to specify additional runtime arguments.
  "runArgs": [
    // Uncomment the next line to use Docker from inside the container. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/samples/docker-in-docker for details.
    // "-v","/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock",
    // Uncomment the next line if you will be using a ptrace-based debugger like C++, Go, and Rust.
    // "--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE", "--security-opt", "seccomp=unconfined"
    // You may want to add a non-root user to your Dockerfile. On Linux, this will prevent
    // new files getting created as root. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root-user
    // for the needed Dockerfile updates and then uncomment the next line.
    // "-u", "vscode"
    "--network",
    "fpl-django_default"
  ],
  // Use 'settings' to set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
  // You can edit these settings after create using File > Preferences > Settings > Remote.
  "settings": {
    "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash",
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/local/bin/pylint",
    "python.linting.enabled": true
  },
  // Uncomment the next line if you want to publish any ports.
  "appPort": [
    8000
  ],
  // Uncomment the next line to run commands after the container is created - for example installing git.
  // "postCreateCommand": "apt-get update && apt-get install -y git",
  // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created in the array below.
  "extensions": [
    "ms-python.python",
  ]
}
```

launch.json:

```
    {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Django",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "args": [
        "runserver",
        "--noreload",
        "--nothreading"
      ],
      "django": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @TheKaizer, which OS you're using now? With Windows OS, sometime I have to use IP like 192.168.x.x to be able to connect to container. And I also have to run my app using this: "./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --noreload --nothreading" to be able to connect from outside

Comment: @ToanQuocHo Im using Mac! Will try with your setup and get back to you!

Comment: Have you tried using the ['Remote - Container' extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) to develop within your container?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo it worked, do you want to add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad to hear that @TheKaizer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to run `manage.py runserver` with this param: `0.0.0.0:8000`, this will tell your app to listen request from any host. Like so:

```
{
      "name": "Python: Django",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "args": [
        "runserver",
        "0.0.0.0:8000",
        "--noreload",
        "--nothreading"
      ],
      "django": true
}
```